# Finding intersection between two text files in windows cmd

Tags: windows, file, command-line

Is there any command on windows to find intersection between two text files?

Example:

```
File1.txt    File2.txt    
Apple        Pie    
Banana       Apple    
Pie
```

Output:

```
Pie    
Apple
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
findstr /i /L /x /g:"File1.txt" "file2.txt"
```

should accomplish that quite nicely.

It finds all strings in file2 that `/x` exactly match `/L` literally `/i` but ignoring case `/g:file` strings in this file.